# Google Calendar Event Link not opening Google Calendar App Event Creation with Details

Tags: android, ios, debugging, google-calendar-api

In Google Calendar, you can generate a link to your event in 2 ways:

1. create it from a template (e.g. https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=Title%20of%20the%20event&details=My%20event%20description&dates=20200915T120000/20200915T130000&ctz=Europe/Rome)
2. copying the link from publish event option of the event itself

but, if you have the Google Calendar App in your phone (iPhone at least)

1. does nothing, just opens up Google Calendar App
2. opens app Google Calendar App in event creation mode, but without details.

Both work correctly online and if you don't have the app.

Anyone knows how to generate a link that opens up the Google Calendar App and gets details of the event prefilled?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not supported per now according to the [G Suite Learning Center](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9302892).

However, you can open that URL in the mobile browser and work with it. As a workaround you can export your event as a file that you can import into Google afterwards. [To do so follow the next documentation](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37118).

Comment: Do you know where it says that in the docs? I'm not seeing anything about creation link text.

Answer (score 0):

add params action=TEMPLATE on url works for me.
https://github.com/InteractionDesignFoundation/add-event-to-calendar-docs/blob/main/services/google.md